# column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to Insert into the Database using parametrized Query. But it is generating an exception:

> column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

```
CDCObj = new ClassDatabaseConnection();
CDCObj.openDatabaseConnection();
CDCObj.cmd_Obj = new SqlCommand("insert into TableCreateAccount values (@c_id,@c_fnm,@c_middlenm,@c_lnm,@c_addline1,@c_addline2,@c_city,@c_state,@c_off_add,@c_emailid,@c_telphone,@c_mono,@c_dob,@c_religion,@c_password,@c_age,@c_usertype,@c_fathernm,@c_mothernm)", CDCObj.con_Obj);
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_id", ACObj.c_id));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_fnm",ACObj.c_fnm));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_middlenm", ACObj.c_mnm));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_lnm", ACObj.c_lnm));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_addline1", ACObj.addline1));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_addline2", ACObj.addline2));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_city", ACObj.c_city));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_state", ACObj.c_state));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_off_add", ACObj.off_address));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_off_contact", ACObj.c_off_contact));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_emailid", ACObj.email_id));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_telphone", ACObj.tel_phoneno));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_mono", ACObj.mobile_no));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_dob", ACObj.d_o_b));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_gender", ACObj.c_gender));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_religion", ACObj.c_religion));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_age", ACObj.c_age));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_password", ACObj.c_password));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_fathernm", ACObj.father_nm));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_mothernm", ACObj.mother_nm));
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_usertype",usertype));

int flag = CDCObj.cmd_Obj.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (flag > 0)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key", "alert('You have registered successfully')", true);
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
else
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key", "alert('Error occured! Please try to register again..')", true);
}
```

This is a my `ClassDatabaseConnection` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public class ClassDatabaseConnection
{
     public SqlConnection con_Obj;
     public SqlCommand cmd_Obj;
     DataTable data_table_Obj;
     SqlDataReader data_reader_Obj;
     SqlDataReader data_adapter_Obj;
     public SqlDataAdapter adp;
     public DataSet ds;
     public ClassDatabaseConnection()
     {
          con_Obj = new SqlConnection();
          con_Obj.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\SEM-5-Final\Project_Civil\App_Data\dbCivilRegistry.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
     }

     public void openDatabaseConnection()
     {
        try
        {
            if(con_Obj.State==ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con_Obj.Open();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e);
        }
    }
    public bool ToAuthenticate(SqlCommand param_Command)
    {
        Object count = param_Command.ExecuteScalar();
        int flag = (int)count;
        if(flag >= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int registered(SqlCommand param_Command)
    {
        Object count = param_Command.ExecuteScalar();
        int flag = (int)count;
        return flag;
    }
    public bool register_update(SqlCommand param_command)
    {
        int i = param_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (i > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void getData()
    {
        cmd_Obj = new SqlCommand("select * from TableAppArrived", con_Obj);
        cmd_Obj.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd_Obj);
        ds = new DataSet("Proj");
        adp.Fill(ds, "app_Proj");
   }
}
```

And My Database Design:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableCreateAccount] (
[CitizenId]                VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
[First_Name]               VARCHAR (15) NULL,
[Middle_Name]              VARCHAR (10) NULL,
[Last_Name]                VARCHAR (15) NULL,
[Fathername]               VARCHAR (30) NULL,
[Mothername]               VARCHAR (30) NULL,
[Residential_Addressline1] VARCHAR (25) NULL,
[Residential_Addressline2] VARCHAR (25) NULL,
[City]                     VARCHAR (20) NULL,
[State]                    VARCHAR (20) NULL,
[Office_Address]           VARCHAR (60) NULL,
[Email_id]                 VARCHAR (15) NULL,
[Telephone_Contact]        VARCHAR (10) NULL,
[Mobile_number]            VARCHAR (10) NULL,
[Date_Of_Birth]            VARCHAR (10) NULL,
[Gender]                   VARCHAR (6)  NULL,
[Religion]                 VARCHAR (10) NULL,
[Password]                 VARCHAR (15) NULL,
[Age]                      INT          NULL,
[Usertype]                 VARCHAR (7)  NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TableCreateAccount] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CitizenId] ASC));
```

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

Your Table definition consists of 20 columns and you are trying to pass 19 parameters in the Insert statement . You didn't declared Office Contact in the Insert Statement.

And also you are trying to pass Duplicate Parameters value for `Office contact`.

```
CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_off_contact", ACObj.c_off_contact));

CDCObj.cmd_Obj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c_telphone", ACObj.tel_phoneno));
```

Define 20 parameters in Insert Statement and declare 20 parameter values only

Answer (score 0):

When you using `Values` without specifying column names in the `insert` statement you should insert based on the order that columns are in your DataBase. for example `@c_fathernm` should appears after the column `@c_lnm` and.... So it should be like this:

```
CDCObj.cmd_Obj = new SqlCommand("insert into TableCreateAccount values (@c_id,@c_fnm,@c_middlenm,@c_lnm,@c_fathernm,@c_mothernm,...)", CDCObj.con_Obj);
```